# Wordpress Material Design issue

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I've created a material design Wordpress theme with material design lite and have been in love with it, but all of a sudden, there is an issue (experienced on Chrome and Safari, not Firefox) where after you get to the footer, you can continue to scroll and there is unidentified white space.

Staging site for theme: http://6f2.c16.myftpupload.com/

I cannot figure out what is causing the issue or how to fix it.

Help would be appreciated and I'd love to share the theme with you if you are interested.

Thanks

Comment: There is an empty div at the bottom of your theme `<div class="mdl-layout__obfuscator"></div>` that has `height: 100%` and `width: 100%`. Delete that and your space will go.

Comment: Change `.mdl-layout { overflow-y:hidden }` I think this solves the problem. Currently  `{overflow-y : auto }`

Answer (score 0):

You nested all the content inside a big div and not the body... i see two scrollbars. Try to search for big containers in your html code or some mistakes about overflow in css code.
Hope to help you.